# Create a singleton in MVC .Net Framework for token authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I have a few questions has I am trying to implement a safeway to keep the token for all my web api calls. I am following the tutorial [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3eIc68VWxgE). Here are the question I have or failed to implement

1. How can I implement a singleton in MVC5 .Net Framework 4.7 application ( I am using autofac for DI in my web api ( I have service layer, domain layer and data layer) But not sure what I would need to for mvc5.
2. Does this mean that all my application controller now need to have a constructor and implement IApiHelper interface to call any web application
3. By converting to interface I can't seam to call my readAsync anymore what would be my alternative.

This is how I call my student api with IHelper however I have issues for reading async.

```
public class StudentsController : Controller
{
    private IApiHelper apiClient;
    public StudentsController(IApiHelper _helper)
    {
        apiClient = _helper;
    }
    // GET: Students
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetStudents()
    {
        List<StudentModel> listStudent = new List<StudentModel>();

        var responseTask = apiClient.GetAsync("Students");
        responseTask.Wait();

        var result = responseTask.Result;
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<StudentModel>>();
            readTask.Wait();

            listStudent = readTask.Result;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(result.ReasonPhrase);
        }

        return Json(listStudent, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

This is basically what I implemented on my IApiHelper.

```
My interface
    public interface IApiHelper
    {
        Task<AuthenticatedUser> Authenticate(string username, string password);
    }
```

This is the implementation

```
    public class ApiHelper : IApiHelper
    {
        private HttpClient apiClient;

        public ApiHelper()
        {
            InitializeClient();
        }

        public void InitializeClient()
        {
            string ApiBaseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["api"];
            apiClient = new HttpClient();
            apiClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(ApiBaseUrl);
            apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }

        public async Task<AuthenticatedUser> Authenticate(string username, string password)
        {
            var data = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password)
            });

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await apiClient.PostAsync("/Token", data))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<AuthenticatedUser>();
                    return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to call something at almost every request - you better use action filters. If you need some service to be a singleton - just register it in your DI as singleton. Also, instead of `readTask.Wait()` just make your action `async`, like `public async Task<ActionResult> GetStudents()` and then `listStudent = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<StudentModel>>()`

Comment: Why you can not call ReasAsync? What's the issue you are facing there? There should be a way in autofac to register a dependency as a Singleton

Comment: This is the method that say its not defined  var responseTask = apiClient.GetAsync("Students"); GetAsync is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with Autofac, DI, or singletons - it's with your interface definition. Your interface, per what you've posted, is:

```cs
public interface IApiHelper
{
    Task<AuthenticatedUser> Authenticate(string username, string password);
}
```

Literally the *only method* on instances of this interface is `Authenticate`.

Thus, when you have this in your code:

```cs
var responseTask = apiClient.GetAsync("Students");
```

Since `apiClient` is an `ApiHelper` that implements `IApiHelper`, there is no `GetAsync` method. If you want to call `GetAsync` on an `IApiHelper`, you need to add that method to the interface and then implement it in `ApiHelper`.

```cs
public interface IApiHelper
{
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string requestUri);
    Task<AuthenticatedUser> Authenticate(string username, string password);
}
```

However, I don't know that I, personally, would necessarily go the interface route if I was allowing calls to arbitrary endpoints using `GET` or `POST` operations.

Instead, I might consider just adding extension methods to `HttpClient` with your helpers.

```cs
public static class HttpClientExtensions
{
    public async Task<AuthenticatedUser> Authenticate(this HttpClient apiClient, string username, string password)
    {
        var data = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password)
        });

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await apiClient.PostAsync("/Token", data))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<AuthenticatedUser>();
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That will allow you to call `apiClient.Authenticate(username, password)` as though it's a method right on the `HttpClient` object, but it won't force you to re-implement all the get/post/whatever operations in an interface.